# What is the best way to AC_CHECK_LIB a library that has additional external dependencies?

Tags: autotools

I've written a library that has a dependency on libxml++ and curl and I am having a hard time figuring out how to use `AC_CHECK_LIB` on my library in another package I've written. The `config.log` file for the new package indicates that there are undefined references to `curl_*` and `xmlpp::*`.

I have `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` setup for libxml++ and curl in my newest package already, and those work, but they are apparently not available for the `AC_CHECK_LIB` call for my own library. (I have the checks for libxml++ and curl before the check for my own library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just provide a `pkg-config` metadata file (`*.pc`) for your package.  That way clients could use `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` and things would Just Work.

But the fact that you're having this problem suggests that you aren't linking your library with libxml++ and libcurl--and you probably should be.  On most modern systems (including Linux), shared libraries know about their dependencies.

Comment: I find the GNU autotoolset to be extremely hard to find *good* documentation on. I was using pkg-config in my first library directly to get data for curl and libxml++ and I was not using AC_CHECK_LIB or PKG_CHECK_MODULES. So, I was linking against them and using pkg-config... just not in this way.

I have already started the process of adding a *.pc file for my first library and things seem to be going more smoothly now.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how do you call `AC_CHECK_LIB`, because it's not in your question, but my guess is that you don't have your dependencies specified as other libraries.

The syntax is:

`AC_CHECK_LIB (library, function, [action-if-found], [action-if-not-found], [other-libraries])`

so put `[-lcurl ...]` as the last argument.

Comment: This didn't answer my question directly, but it did point me in the correct direction. Thanks!